# confusion about the http multi/form-data request

Tags: http

The http request is as follows:
[image]

The server code is as follows:

```
 POST = request.POST
 print POST.get('text')
 with open('/home/shenwenwu/test.wav','wb') as f:
     f.write(POST.get('audio'))
```

The audio send is only 35884 bytes, why the server recv 60Kb?

Comment: There is more than just raw audio data being sent. The audio is only 1 piece of the overall MIME data that is being posted. The audio is only 35884 bytes, but the entire MIME data is 36099 bytes, which includes MIME headers, MIME boundaries, JSON, and audio.  The server should only be receiving 36099 bytes (+ the few HTTP headers), certainly nowhere near 60K. How do you know it is receiving 60K? What are you looking at for that number?

Comment: Why 60KB the server recv? The request only 30KB

Comment: If I had to guess (and please, don't make people guess - learn to debug your code properly), `POST.get()` is probably returning the `audio` data as Unicode text in UTF-16 format, instead of as binary data, and thus you would be writing 70K to the file rather than 35K.  What language are you coding this in?  What does the `POST.get()` documentation say about how it handles binary data?